# How to do multiple grouping and multiple aggregation with order by in java streaming?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am performing some aggregation and grouping over List<Map<String, Object>, I have tried few things as below but not getting proper result format, please help me out here if you can.

```
List<Map<String, Object>> lm = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    
    Map<String, Object> ms= new HashMap<String, Object>();
    ms.put("name", "abc");
    ms.put("color", "red");
    ms.put("price", 3000);
    ms.put("days", 3);
    
    lm.add(ms);
    
    
    ms= new HashMap<String, Object>();
    ms.put("name", "pqr");
    ms.put("color", "blue");
    ms.put("price", 2500);
    ms.put("days", 4);
    
    lm.add(ms);
    
    ms= new HashMap<String, Object>();
    ms.put("name", "pqr");
    ms.put("color", "blue");
    ms.put("price", 500);
    ms.put("days", 3);
    
    ms= new HashMap<String, Object>();
    ms.put("name", "xyz");
    ms.put("color", "orange");
    ms.put("price", 5000);
    ms.put("days", 30);
    
    lm.add(ms);
```

So the above data will be something like in below format:

```
    Name Color Price Days
    abc   red  3000   3
    pqr   blue 2500   4
```

Code for summarizing is as below:

```
 Map<Object, Map<Object, Object>> map = lm.stream()
                     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(g -> g.get("name").toString(),
                             Collectors.groupingBy(g -> g.get("color").toString(),
                             Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), list -> {
                                 Double occupancy = list.stream().collect(
                                         Collectors.averagingInt(s -> (int)s.get("price")));
                                 int efficiency = (int) list.stream().collect(
                                         Collectors.summingInt(s -> (int)s.get("days")));
                                 return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(occupancy, efficiency);
                             }))));

             System.out.println(map);
```

output of this is coming as below :

```
{pqr={blue=2500.0=4}, abc={red=3000.0=3}, xyz={orange=5000.0=30}}
```

But it should be like:

```
[{"name":"pqr", "color":"blue", "price": 1500, "days":7},
 {"name":"abc", "color":"red", "price": 3000, "days":3},
 ......]
```

I am not sure what is wrong I am doing please help me out.

Comment: Can you briefly explain what goal are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I want to find avg of price and sum of days by grouping name and color and result should be in list of map format.

Comment: Yes that I understand, but I want it to modify somehow in format which I want, there should be way, I am finding it

Comment: As soon as you call `Collectors.averagingInt` and/or `Collectors.summingInt`, the stream will be reduced to an integer. Hence, you will not get the map object result as you are expecting.

Comment: Use of `Collectors.toMap` with a clean `mergeFunction` does the trick in such cases! You need to design the `key` wisely, such as it accounts for both the attributes, e.g. `g -> Arrays.asList(g -> g.get("name").toString(), g -> g.get("color").toString()`. You would after that mostly be interested in the `values` of the resutant `Map`.